# Angular HttpClient get method returns object with wrongly named attributes

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have a web controller with a GET method `Products`. This method returns `Enumerable` of type `Product`.

```
        public class Product
        {
            public float Price;
            public string Name;
            public string ImageURL;
            public int Quantity;

            public Product()
            {
                this.Quantity = 1;
            }
        }
```

I have created an Angular component which reads data provided by the controller method as follows:

```
constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    this.grandTotal = 0;
    this.httpClient = http;
    this.url = baseUrl;
    http.get<Product[]>(baseUrl + 'api/SampleData/Products').subscribe(result => {
      this.products = result;
      this.slicedProducts = new Array<Product[]>();
      for (let i = 0; i < this.products.length / 3; i++) {
        this.slicedProducts[i] = this.products.slice(i * 3, i * 3 + 3);
      }

    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
```

My problem is that property names in the objects at Angular side are incorrectly named, e.g.: `Product.Quantity` is `Product.quantity`, so when I try to use these properties later on in my functions, I have an error that `Quantity` does not exist. When I use `quantity`, the code works.

Comment: post the code where you get the error

Comment: It depends from your back end json serializer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Java. Check your settings for the object conversion from Java object to Json object. Assuming you are using Spring Boot on the backend, you may need to configure your [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to keep the field names as is. I assume the fields are converted to [Camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) by default.